# Strobe light is working fine but doesn't work very well on click

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have created the following strobe light. I want it to start on the press of a button and to stop if pressed again. Right now when it is open and I click, it closes but, on clicking again nothing happens!

Without the click listener, it starts on the start of the app but works great, but there is no way to stop it.

```
    public class Small extends Activity {

    private MMAdView adViewFromXml;
    RefreshHandler handler;
    ImageButton knob;
    int n=100000;
    Camera mCamera;
    Parameters params;
    int delay = 400; // in ms
    public boolean on;
    public boolean works;
    Thread logotimer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_small_button);

        knob = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pic);
        strobe();

        knob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View iv) {
                  if(works == true){
                      logotimer.interrupt();
                  }else if(works != true)
                  {
                      strobe();
                  }
              }
            });

                }); 

    }

    /** Turn the devices FlashLight on */
    public void turnOn() {
      if (mCamera != null) {
        // Turn on LED
        params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        on = true;
      }

    }

    /** Turn the devices FlashLight off */
    public void turnOff() {
      // Turn off flashlight
      if (mCamera != null) {
        params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.stopPreview();


      }
      on = false;
    }

    /** Toggle the flashlight on/off status */
    /*public void toggleFlashLight() {
        if (!on) { // Off, turn it on
        turnOn();
      } else { // On, turn it off
        turnOff();
      }
}*/
    private void strobe(){
      Thread logotimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            // Switch on the cam for app's life
            if (mCamera == null) {
              // Turn on Cam
              try{
                mCamera = Camera.open();
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
              }
              try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            int logotimer = 0;
            while(!interrupted() && logotimer <5000) {
                logotimer = logotimer ++;
                works = true;

                if (!on) { // Off, turn it on
                    turnOn();
                  } else if(on == true) { // On, turn it off
                    turnOff();
                  }
                sleep(delay);
            }
            if (mCamera == null) {
              mCamera.stopPreview();
              mCamera.release();
              mCamera = null;
            }
          } catch (InterruptedException e){ 

            e.printStackTrace(); 
          }
        }
      };logotimer.start();
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
01-08 15:17:33.807: W/System.err(28814): java.lang.InterruptedException
01-08 15:17:33.808: W/System.err(28814):    at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
01-08 15:17:33.808: W/System.err(28814):    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
01-08 15:17:33.808: W/System.err(28814):    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:995)
01-08 15:17:33.809: W/System.err(28814):    at com.light.oid.Small$4.run(Small.java:163)
```

Comment: when you click on knob, you release the camera, but don't stop the strobe loop.

Comment: you need to stop the loop in the onclick method, and leave the camera releasing to the thread.

Comment: @njzk2  Can you please be more specific,perhaps show me some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add strobe() call inside onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View iv) {
    if(works) {
        logotimer.interrupt();

    } else {
        //mCamera = Camera.open(); //remove this
        //and add strobe()
        strobe(); 
    }
}
```

Also, you have global Thread logotimer, but in your strobe() method, you are creating a local variable with the same name, so when clicking button, logotimer is null, because the local shadows the global.

In strobe(), change:

```
 private void strobe(){
     Thread logotimer = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
```

to:

```
 private void strobe(){
     logotimer = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
```

Comment: logcat `01-07 21:24:50.477: E/Web Console(30326): Uncaught ReferenceError: MMJS is not defined at null:1
01-07 21:24:52.763: W/System.err(30326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
01-07 21:24:52.764: W/System.err(30326):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
01-07 21:24:52.765: W/System.err(30326):  at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1589)
01-07 21:24:52.765: W/System.err(30326):  at com.light.oid.Small.turnOn(Small.java:100)
01-07 21:24:52.765: W/System.err(30326):  at com.light.oid.Small$4.run(Small.java:154)
`

Comment: So.. do you have any idea how should i do it?

Comment: See the edit in the logcat,it is like that after the changes that u told me to do so

Comment: And i accept your answer because you brought me closer to solving the problem and your hard work.

Comment: Thanks. The exception happens when your thread in in sleep, and you call interrupt(). Try rewriting your code using Handler and Runnable, then to cancel, you can do: handler.removeCallbacks(runnableName)